# Peculiar situation with GCS

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-console

In my GCS bucket, I have a folder structure where the naming convention was done incorrectly. Its named as "11 Jan. 2021 - Documents and Spreads". This is causing the gsutil to throw an exception whenever I try to navigate or download the files. I can't rename or move the objects in that folder. How can I get around this?

Comment: Show the command and error message.

Comment: The name of the folder do respect the [naming conventions for objects](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/naming-objects#objectnames). I created a folder in my bucket, stored two CSV and running the following command: `gsutil cp -r "gs://[CHANGE-FOR-YOURBUCKET-NAME]/11 Jan. 2021 - Documents and Spreads" .` (don't forget to include the . at the end and change for your bucket name) on the Cloud Shell downloads the files without any issues. Besides showing the command and error message please advise on Cloud SDK version (running `gcloud version`) and gsutil version (runnnig `gsutil version`).

Comment: Also please advise about your OS (or where exactly are you trying to download the files).

Comment: You OS and the shell that you (on windows, CMD or Powershell)